# Amazon AWS ECS Container Docker Port not binding correctly

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, port, amazon-ecs, ecs-taskdefinition

I have deployed a docker Image via ECS Task Definitions picked up from ECR.
The Task definition json is given below.

[image: 1]

I have mapped container port as 80 &
Network Mode : `awsvpc`

But when the ECS service is started and docker runs in an EC2 instance but the ports are not mapped. I verified the same by logging into the EC2 instance and triggering

`docker ps`

[image: 2]

I am using Load Balancer as of now. Wanted to first get the containers working and accessible
via 80 port.

Kindly help me figure out what is wrong in the given config

Comment: Which NetworkMode are you using?

Comment: Can you confirm that you are not able to access on these ports? As you're using awsvpc mode your task will have its own ENI. You'll need to grab the IP address and perform a curl against that IP

Comment: Yup I have tested that, the ports are not accessible

Comment: Any luck with that? It still happens - no matter if network mode host or awsvpc

Answer (score 0):

With `awsvpc` the `Security Group >> Inbound rules` are important.
You need to make sure that the `Container port mapping` is actually allowed in the `Security Group >> Inbound rules` of your `ECS Service`

[image]